# Ruby custom shell with custom commands

Tags: ruby

I would like to write a Ruby program that is basically a shell with custom commands. This means that after calling "**ruby app.rb**" the user will enter a shell which supports special commands that I wrote.

I used `loop do ... end` to create a basic loop that processes user input. I also used an array of strings to store all available commands, and a hash table with help messages for each available command. But this is very cumbersome.

I would like to know how to **elegantly define custom commands with flags, some of which are mandatory** (e.g. create -f "~/file.txt" --READONLY -v). Not only that, I need the "**help**" command of my shell to output info about every single custom command, including flags, AND to have a "**menu**" command that lists every available command. As a last resort, I thought of simply creating a bunch of .rb files for every command and then using OptionParser for flags and arguments, since I know of no way to make OptionParser work with functions instead of files.

This is what I came up with so far:

```
class Shell
    @@input = ""

    # List of all commands
    @@commands = [
        "help",
        "exit"
    ]

    # Help messages associated with commands
    @@help_strings = Hash[
        "help" => "Outputs this info.",
        "exit" => "Closes the program."
    ]


    def self.start
        # bash clear screen command
        system("clear")

        loop do
             print (">> ")
             input = gets.chomp

             case input
             when "help"
                 for com in @@commands
                     puts("#{com}: #{@@help_strings[com]}")
                 end
             when "exit"
                 # bash clear screen command
                 system("clear")
                 break
             else
                 puts("Unknown commands: #{input}")
                 puts("Type \"help\" for more info.")
             end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Do try and steer away from using double-at variables (`@@`)  and instead use constants here. Even better, since this apparently can't be instantiated, use a `module` instead of a `class`, or move all this to an instance method like `Shell.new.start`.

Comment: I cannot make "input" a constant, since I made it a class variable instead of a variable local to the loop in the first place to avoid having to create it anew after every single input.

Comment: `@@input` shouldn't exist. `input` is already a local variable in the `start` block, and it's not related to `@@input` in any way.

Comment: Well this is awkward.

Comment: Nothing wrong with things being a bit confused so long as you clear them all up before it becomes a problem.

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a bit that goes into creating a robust [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), but there are a few optimizations you can take to simplify what you've got here.

1. Create a separate `Runner` class that holds all of your commands. Use `methods` and `instance_methods` to get a list of supported commands without maintaining a separate list.
2. Check whether a command is supported, then call the method directly rather than using a `case` statement.
3. Capture `ctrl+c` to exit your loop cleanly.

```rb
class Shell
  class Runner
    def supported_method?(method)
      # This will return an array of the instance methods that are not provided by ancestors
      (methods - Object.instance_methods).include?(method.to_sym)
    end

    def help
      puts "[TODO: Help info]"
    end

    def exit
      system "clear"
    end
  end

  def self.start
    runner = Runner.new
    loop do 
      print (">> ")
      input = gets.chomp
      if runner.supported_method?(input)
        runner.send(input)
      else 
        puts("Unknown commands: #{input}\nType \"help\" for more info.")
      end
    end
  rescue SystemExit, Interrupt, IRB::Abort
    puts "\nShutting down."
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Even at a glance, your advice was very helpful. Unfortunately, I still cannot come up with a way to define command flags and arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do this:

- Make a `Command` class, with an `inherited` hook that registers the subclass in the `Command`
- Make make each command a subclass of `Command`, with a method that produces an `OptionParser` for that command, a method that produces a short description, and another method that accepts `args` and executes the command
- In your REPL, `command_name, *agrs = Shellwords.shellsplit(line)`, find the registered command that matches the name, get its `OptionParser` and run it on `args`, then invoke the command's executor method
- For `help`, just iterate on all the registered commands and get their descriptions
- For `help <command>`, just get the command's `OptionParser`, then display its help
- Use the `readline` module instead of `gets` so your users don't curse at you

EDIT: Here's the barebones example:

```
require 'optparse'
require 'shellwords'
require 'readline'

class Command
  @commands = {}

  def self.inherited(klass)
    klass.new.then { |instance| @commands[instance.name] = instance }
  end

  def self.commands
    @commands
  end

  def name
    self.class.to_s.downcase
  end

  def opts(parser)
    parser.program_name = name
  end

  def args; (0..Float::Infinity); end
end

class BangShell
  def self.start
    while line = Readline.readline("! ", true)
      name, *args = Shellwords.shellsplit(line)
      command = Command.commands[name]
      unless command
        STDERR.puts "Error: Don't know about #{name}!"
        next
      end
      command.opts(opts = OptionParser.new)
      opts.parse!(args, into: options = {})
      unless command.args === args.length
        STDERR.puts "Error: Invalid number of arguments for #{name}!"
        next
      end
      if options.empty?           # this is Ruby being weird about **; but I think it's changing in 3.0
        command.call(*args)
      else
        command.call(*args, **options)
      end
    end
  end
end

class Echo < Command
  def call(*args, n: false)
    print args.join(' ')
    puts unless n
  end

  def description
    "Echoes arguments to console"
  end

  def opts(parser)
    super
    parser.on('-n', 'Do not emit newline')
  end
end

class Help < Command
  def call(name=nil)
    if name
      command = Command.commands[name]
      unless command
        STDERR.puts "Error: Don't know about #{name}!"
        return
      end
      puts command.opts(OptionParser.new)
    else
      puts "Commands:"
      Command.commands.each do |name, command|
        puts command.name.ljust(20) + command.description
      end
    end
  end

  def description
    "Shows help"
  end

  def args; (0..1); end
end

BangShell.start
```

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it.

Comment: @Amadan — this is great, but I think you have a small bug. `unless command.args === args.length` is calling `Echo.args` but there is no such method.

Comment: @coreyward I renamed the method, but forgot to rename it in the parent class. Fixed now. (Also, this is more like a proof of concept, more work would be needed for something satisfactory, I think...)